# Why does using pytest.skip() give me different results when I copy freeCodeCamp's code?

Tags: pytest, brownie

```
def test_get_entrance_fee():
    if network.show_active() not in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
        pytest.skip()
    # Arrange
    lottery = deploy_lottery()
    # Act
    # 2,000 eth / usd
    # usdEntryFee is 50
    # 2000/1 == 50/x == 0.025
    expected_entrance_fee = Web3.toWei(0.025, "ether")
    entrance_fee = lottery.getEntranceFee()
    # Assert
    assert expected_entrance_fee == entrance_fee
```

Excuting an order

> brownie test -k test_get_entrance_fee --network rinkeby

the result should be like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM215.png)

but I got below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv6jP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID` to `.env` file